# Save a custom cursor created by CreateIconIndirect to a cur file

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, cursor

I've been trying to write code that loads a .png file, attaches hotspot information, and saves it to a .cur file.

So far I have code to create a `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` object, which I'll post below:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(source_image);
IconInfo inf = new IconInfo();
GetIconInfo(bmp.GetHicon(), ref inf);
inf.xHotspot = /* code to get x hotspot */;
inf.yHotspot = /* code to get y hotspot */;
inf.fIcon = false;
IntPtr iconPtr = CreateIconIndirect(ref inf);
return new Cursor(iconPtr);
```

I took it directly from [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors).

I've gotten the cursor to work properly within my application, there just seems to be no way to save it to a file.
Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a function to save to a file, you probably have to write out the file with correct headers on your own, see [Icons in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) for format details (x and y in planes and bpp fields IIRC)

Comment: That's what I ended up having to do to make custom cursors, save to an ico and change the necessary bits in a hex editor.  I might end up actually doing that programmatically though.

Comment: And yes, I used Icon.Save to save it to a MemoryStream, then just set the required bytes by hand.

Comment: @MiffTheFox I need to save .cur files, can you give me a hand with it? how did you do it programatically in c#? Thank you.